# Defining React Prop Keys When Calling Static Child Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, random

I'm trying to better understand the role of keys in React components. I've read quite a bit but every example I've seen (like the one in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) or [the great explanation on S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)) assumes the data coming into the component is dynamic.

The examples all apply keys with array index values or using something like `.map()` to assign database IDs dynamically to each instance of the child component, and satisfy React's need for keys.

My example is on a static site with static content coming into the child component that gets called a couple of times. Best I figured, I could create a random number generator function `getRandomInt` and apply the key that way.

Unfortunately this results in the familiar React error:

> Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.
>   Check the render method of `CaseStudyOpinionSummary`. It was passed a
>   child from `DiagnosticCaseStudy`.

Where am I going wrong?

Parent component (`DiagnosticCaseStudy`)

```
import React from 'react'
import CaseStudyOpinionSummary from '../../../components/CaseStudyOpinionSummary'

export default class DiagnosticCaseStudy extends React.Component {

  getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CaseStudyOpinionSummary
        part="Part One"
        partTitle="Diagnosis"
        partSubtitle="Primary Care Encounter"
        partSummary="Short brief"
        key={ this.getRandomInt(0, 100000) } 
      />
      <CaseStudyOpinionSummary
        part="Part Two"
        partTitle="Medication and Management"
        partSubtitle="Initial Gastroenterologist Encounter"
        partSummary="Another short brief"
        key={ this.getRandomInt(0, 100000) } 
      />
    )
  }
```

Child component (`CaseStudyOpinionSummary`)

```
import React from 'react'

export default class CaseStudyOpinionSummary extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (   
      <div> 
        <section className="lightest-gray-bg">
          <section className="aga-cs-container-short">
            <section className="aga-container">
              <h2 className="aga-cs-orange-title">{[this.props.part, ": ", this.props.partTitle ]}</h2>
              <h2 className="aga-cs-question-title">{ this.props.partSubtitle }</h2>
              { this.props.partSummary }
            </section>
          </section>
        </section>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You only need to use keys when you are rendering an array of React elements (e.g. the result of `map` is an array, like you mentioned). You don't need keys otherwise. If you random a key every render, that means that the component will be unmounted and a new one mounted every render (!), which is not what you want. In the case of `DiagnosticCaseStudy` you can just wrap your components in a `div`, or e.g. give them each key `1` and `2` if you want to return an array.

Comment: What's the purpose of rendering this: `{[this.props.part, ": ", this.props.partTitle ]}`? Are you just trying to concatenate strings? If so, try just concatenating them for real, and then rendering that string, instead of rendering an array. `{this.props.part + ": " + this.props.partTitle}`

Comment: Your parent component must return only a single element. Wrap the two child components in a `div` or `React.Fragment`.

Comment: Good feedback @Tholle - so what exactly is react doing under the hood with wrap your component in a `<div>`?

Comment: @staypuftman Sorry, I read the `DiagnosticCaseStudy` wrong. You need to return a single element from the render method, like robhirstio mentioned. [I wanted to highlight the difference between these two approaches](https://codesandbox.io/s/13349lx9qq). Notice that sibling components only need keys when they are inside an array.

Comment: @Tholle Just to add a small note: Keys can also be used to "reset" a component when its context changes. Although this is not relevant for this particular question.

Comment: @trixn Yes, you're right, hence the "that means that the component will be unmounted and a new one mounted every render (!)" in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React only needs the `key` prop to distinguish between sibling components in an array. You don't need the `key` prop for regular sibling components.

```js
class AppWithArray extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      {[
        <div key="1"> test1 </div>,
        <div key="2"> test2 </div>
      ]}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class AppWithoutArray extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div> test3 </div>
        <div> test4 </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <AppWithArray />
    <AppWithoutArray />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

When a component gets a new `key` prop, the old one will be unmounted and thrown away and a new one will be created and mounted. You almost never use the `key` prop outside of arrays, but it can be a nice technique to keep in mind if you ever need to create an entirely new component.

```js
class Timer extends React.Component {
  timer = null;
  state = { count: 0 };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({ count: prevState.count + 1 }));
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.count}</div>;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { timerKey: 1 };

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ timerKey: 2 });
    }, 5000);
  }

  render() {
    return <Timer key={this.state.timerKey} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that second example, interesting use case I hadn't considered.